# How can I create a variable that takes only a specific range from a another variable?

Tags: range

I have the following problem: participants answered questionnaires over the course of three days, multiple times a day. I am taking a look at the questionnaires between finishing work and going to sleep. I have a variable called "type" that specifies which questionnaire was answered (e.g. start_work, finish_work...).
I want to select all the questionnaires from the end of work until going to sleep, usually called "FA". The problem is that some participants also missed a questionnaire, called "Missing" and I want to include them in this time frame. But this "Missing" type could have also been present at other time frames (during work). So there are multiple "Missing" questionnaires during the day that are getting in the way.

I can't just compute a new variable with the "FA" questionnaires, cause otherwise the "Missing" ones are missing. But I also have problems coming up with a range from e.g. "finish_work" to "sleeping_time". I tried the LAG function, tried some sort of loop, but am starting to think I would need Python for it? I'm really confused and a beginner at SPSS, so I'd be grateful for any help.